# xslt javascript: error when trying to define function with a name including a dash

Tags: javascript, xslt, xmlspy

Following [David Carlisle blogspot exslt node-set function](http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/exslt-node-set-function.html) I added the below to my stylesheet:

```
...xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"...

<msxsl:script language="jscript" implements-prefix="exslt">
    this['node-set'] = function (x) {
        return x;
    }
</msxsl:script>
```

If I understand correctly, this way of defining a function in javascript (using `this`) is necessary because of the dash in the function name; defining it as `function node-set(){...}` will not work and `this['z']` is equivalent to `this.z`.
The problem is that this script is rejected by the script-validator in XML Spy.

> Script Compile Error(s) (relative to script begin):
>
> Line 1, Character
>   3: Syntax error
>
> Line 1, Character 31: Expected identifier "
>         this['node-set'] = function (x) {           return x;       }   "

No problem at all  when I define `function nodeset(){...}` but somehow it does not allow me to use the construct `this['...']`, not even `this['nodeset']` where a function name without dashes is used.

Anyone know what I should do about this? David, perhaps? :-)

Comment: Try deleting the space between ``function`` and ``(x)`` so it just reads ``function(x)``. The ``Expected identifier`` makes me think the parser expects a form of either ``function funcName(x)`` or ``function(x)`` -- that is, whitespace being significant.

Comment: no luck - same error :-( I also tried removing the spaces around the `=`, just in case.

Comment: Well, Javascript allows named functions to be assigned to variables. What about ``this['node-set'] = function nodeSet(x) {``?

Comment: @DavidEllis no that does not work either. I am just guessing but it may have something to do with XML Spy itself - I searched for javascript settings but could not find these...

Comment: Maestro13, What browser uses XML SPY as its XSLT processor? AFAIK none.

Comment: Maestro13, (Continued): Therefore no problem at all. Just stop using Altova.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev I use Altova XML Spy 2011 which uses the installed IE version as a default - IE9 for me. This is used for displaying html results or XML+associated stylesheet. It has a separate built-in xslt 1.0/2.0 processor for debugging purposes.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev and one can choose a different available xslt processor (saxon, xalan, whatever) when debugging by supplying the command line call format.

Comment: @Maestro13: This is what I am saying -- the XSLT code is OK, you can just use a different XSLT processor for testing this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked this with Altova support desk, asking about the error when using "this", and they replied as follows:

`The code in question is non-standard for XSLT 1.0, using MSXML-only features.`

Not a clear answer, but I deduce that this implies that XML Spy's javascript version does not support "this".
I will thus include the code where I need it and just check the code by opening the XML + referred stylesheet in a list of browsers, not bothering about the javascript error that XML Spy mentions during xslt edit or save.